# Dynamic Slider value....but! Updating the serial monitor as the value changes..Not when the slider is only let go [Running on ESP8266 Web Server]

Tags: javascript

So I've included the Pastebin for the code here.. https://pastebin.com/F7JU8unU This is the code I'm using and it works really well for local dynamic changes...But this is set up to give the response back from the client to the server...but right now the value changes on the website..it's dynamic and amazing.....but it only updates the server when the slider is let go which isn't great. You can upload this code to your computer and try it out on your own ESP8266...just change the SSID and password, go to the IP that is given on the serial monitor and you'll see what I mean....Hopefully, someone can help me out..I'm pretty new to this stuff here's the part of the code I think needs to be looked at.
client.println("<input type="range" min="-255" max="255" class="slider" id="servoSlider" onchange="servo(this.value)" value=""+valueString+""/>");

````
        client.println("<script>var slider = document.getElementById(\"servoSlider\");");
        client.println("var servoP = document.getElementById(\"servoPos\"); servoP.innerHTML = slider.value;");
        client.println("slider.oninput = function() { slider.value = this.value; servoP.innerHTML = this.value; }");
        client.println("$.ajaxSetup({timeout:1000}); function servo(pos) { ");
        client.println("$.get(\"/?value=\" + pos + \"&\"); {Connection: close};}</script>");
        ```
````

Changing oninput and onchange hasn't done the trick.....the value still only gets updated on the serial monitor when you let go of the slider.....the value of the slider is updating on the website. But not updating on the serial side, until you let go.